# ggplot : Line Plot with Standard Deviations on X Axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, figure

I'm trying to use ggplot to create a figure where the X axis is +/-1 SDs of the X variable. I'm not sure what this sort of figure is called or how to go about making it. I've googled ggplot line plot with SDs but have not found anything similar. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Here is reproducible code that illustrates where I am at now:

```
library(tidyverse, ggplot2)
iris <- iris
iris <- iris %>% filter(Species == "virginica" | Species == "setosa")

ggplot(iris, aes(x=scale(Sepal.Length), y=Sepal.Width, group = Species, 
                       shape=Species, linetype=Species))+ 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(title="Iris Data Example",x="Sepal Length", y = "Sepal Width")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

There are two main differences between the figure I originally posted and this one:

A) The original figure only contains +1 and -1 SDs, while my example contains -1, 0 +1 and +2.

B) The original figure had a Y mean for -1 and +1 SD on the X axis, while my example has the datapoints all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scale` function in R subtracts the mean and divides the result by a standard deviations, such that the resulting variable can be interpreted as 'number of standard deviations from the mean'. See also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score).

In ggplot2, you can wrap a variable you want with `scale()` on the fly in the `aes()` function.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(scale(displ), cty)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

### EDIT:

It seems I've not carefully read the legend of the first figure: it seems as if the authors have binned the data based on whether they exceed a positive or negative standard deviation. To bin the data that way we can use the `cut` function. We can then use the `limits` of the scale to exclude the `(-1, 1]` bin and the `labels` argument to make prettier axis labels.

I've switched around the x and y aesthetics relative to your example, otherwise one of the species didn't have any observations in one of the categories.

```r
library(tidyverse, ggplot2)
iris <- iris
iris <- iris %>% filter(Species == "virginica" | Species == "setosa")

ggplot(iris, 
       aes(x = cut(scale(Sepal.Width), breaks = c(-Inf, -1,1, Inf)), 
           y = Sepal.Length, group = Species, 
           shape = Species, linetype = Species))+ 
  geom_line(stat = "summary", fun = mean) + 
  scale_x_discrete(
    limits = c("(-Inf,-1]", "(1, Inf]"),
    labels = c("-1 SD", "+ 1SD")
  ) +
  labs(title="Iris Data Example",y="Sepal Length", x = "Sepal Width")+
  theme_bw()
#> Warning: Removed 73 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I think that gets me halfway there, but I still need the datapoints to all cluster around those +/-1 SD points, rather than be scattered throughout like in the graph you have there. i.e., have a single mean for 'cty' (y axis) at each of those SD points along the x axis. Is there a way to group the y points around those newly scaled x points so they resemble the original figure I posted?

Comment: Can you upload a reproducible example with (dummy) data of what you have so far that illustrates the problem? I'm having a hard time understanding what the objective is exactly without inspecting the code /data.

Comment: Good suggestion! I just updated the original post and uploaded a reproducible example with the iris dataset from tidyverse. It shows where I'm at with my own code.